# Tool for renaming the resource keys and their occurences in the source files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resources

Is there any Workaround/Tool for renaming the **Resource Keys** from the  resource file .

I also need to replace all such occurences in the source code with my new (renamed resource key).

**Is there any tool available to automate this task.?**

Could someone put in some thoughts on this.?

thanks,
vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the latest version of Resharper provides some resource refactoring tools. There is also a tool called RGreatEx you might want to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You probably realize this, but the resx files are simple xml docs.  You can open them in your favorite text editor and edit with find/replace, regular expression, vim, keyboard macro's.  I doesn't give you a one stop shop to rename resources in the resx and the code at the same time, but might still be a viable option